# Commuting circuit equivalent to $CX_{ij}CX_{jk}$

Tags: circuit-construction

Commuting groups are useful to perform circuit optimization.

There is a big branch of research working on circuit construction by means of [CZ gates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.08691.pdf) and/or [EASE gates](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2022-01-27-634/). Up to reach an efficient construction (in terms of commutativity), of Clifford circuits.

I am looking for an easy use case, which represents the main issue with the use of $CX$ gates. Namely a $CX_{ij}CX_{jk}$:

[image]

I would like to see a commuting circuit implementing $CX_{ij}CX_{jk}$, possibly without auxilliary qubits (which case is also of interest and can be a valid answer).

EDIT: I also consider construction based on Ising gates as a valid answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what way you want it to commute and in what way you want it to be similar to a chain of cnots? It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear because it has no answer. I am looking for some circuit, equivalent to this, but composed by commuting gates.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is related to this one: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28753/how-to-store-error-caused-by-circuit-manipulation/28760?noredirect=1#comment38195_28760